# Get Part of the String if with conditional prefix [+ and suffix +]

Tags: php, string

How can I get part of the string with conditional prefix `[+` and suffix `+]`, and then return all of it in an array?

example:

```
$string = 'Lorem [+text+] Color Amet, [+me+] The magic who [+do+] this template';

// function to get require
function getStack ($string, $prefix='[+', $suffix='+]') {
    // how to get get result like this?
    $result = array('text', 'me', 'do'); // get all the string inside [+ +]

    return $result;
}
```

many thanks...

Comment: This should be a fairly simple regex. Something like `preg_match_all("/\\[\\+(.*?)\\+\\]/");` and then get group 1 of the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**preg_match_all**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) as:

```
function getStack ($string, $prefix='[+', $suffix='+]') {
        $prefix = preg_quote($prefix);
        $suffix = preg_quote($suffix);
        if(preg_match_all("!$prefix(.*?)$suffix!",$string,$matches)) {
                return $matches[1];
        }
        return array();
}
```

[**Code In Action**](http://www.ideone.com/rEmyd)

Comment: You might want to add the delimiter `/` to the `preg_quote()` calls.

Comment: @codaddict: I think you misunderstood BoltClock. `preg_quote` does not escape the delimiter unless it’s one of PCRE’s special characters. So if you’re using `/` or `!` as delimiter, you need to pass it to `preg_quote` to have it escaped.

Comment: @Gumbo: The manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php says:  The special regular expression characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -` which includes `!`. So it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a solution with [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok):

```
function getStack ($string, $prefix='[+', $suffix='+]') {
    $matches = array();
    strtok($string, $prefix);
    while (($token = strtok($suffix)) !== false) {
        $matches[] = $token;
        strtok($prefix);
    }
    return $matches;
}
```